# PHP upload image not working

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I have some problem with the upload of image with php. I don't know why but i'm not able to complete the upload.
Here is my code :

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
$uploaddir = '/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['files']['name']['0']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['name']['0'], __DIR__.'/../ticket/'. $_FILES["files"]['name']['0'])) {
    echo "Uploaded";
} else {
   echo "File was not uploaded";
}

echo 'Some Information:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

This is what I received when I call this services

```
 File was not uploadedSome Information:Array
 (
[files] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => IMG_20180531_223116_725.jpg?1527806109166
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => multipart/form-data
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => /membri/.dummy/temp/phpM2iSBN
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 112903
            )

    )
```

)

Thank you if you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to move the file in the local temp directory

`$_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['0']` not the file name

so:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name']['0'], __DIR__.'/../ticket/'. $_FILES["files"]['name']['0'])) {
```